# How to invoke a callback function with arguments

Tags: javascript, callback

I have this main function which takes 1 string and 2 callback functions as the argument. Below is the code.

```
function confirmYesNo(confirmMessage, confirmCallback, cancelCallback) {
    $("#yes-button").click(function () {
         confirmCallback(); //How do I pass confirmCallback arguments
    });
    ...
}
```

Here is how the function is invoked

```
function confirmYesNoTest() {
    var confirmContent = "Some Message"
    var id = "1";
    confirmYesNo(confirmContent,
        function (id) { alert(id); }, //alerts undefined
        function () { alert("Cancel Clicked"); });
}
```

The problem is that the id variable above (which is set to 1) comes out as "undefined" when the confirmCallback executes. Seems something related to scope, but I am not able to get this working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The callback should not take any arguments. You could capture the id in a closure:

```
function confirmYesNoTest() {
    var confirmContent = "Some Message"
    var id = "1";
    confirmYesNo(
        confirmContent,
        function () { alert(id); },
        function () { alert("Cancel Clicked"); }
    );
}
```

Alternatively, if you didn't want to use closures you could pass the id as parameter to the callback:

```
function confirmYesNo(confirmMessage, id, confirmCallback, cancelCallback) {
    $("#yes-button").click(function () {
         confirmCallback(id);
    });
    ...
}
```

and when invoking:

```
function confirmYesNoTest() {
    var confirmContent = "Some Message"
    var id = "1";
    confirmYesNo(
        confirmContent,
        id,
        function (id) { alert(id); },
        function () { alert("Cancel Clicked"); }
    );
}
```

Now you can use the callbacks as named functions:

```
var confirmCallback = function(id) {
    alert(id);
};
```

and then:

```
function confirmYesNoTest() {
    var confirmContent = "Some Message"
    var id = "1";
    confirmYesNo(
        confirmContent,
        id,
        confirmCallback,
        function () { alert("Cancel Clicked"); }
    );
}
```

Comment: Your first approach suits well, particularly when I don't know the exact number of parameters that will be required for the callback. I will be able to capture multiple parameters in closure as mentioned above without worrying about how many of these are there.